# Column set to hidden when editing existing xlsx file

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

I'm editing a current template.xlsx using openpyxl library, but when adding new values to one of the worksheets, the columns get hidden

```
workbook = xlsx.load_workbook(filename='template.xlsx')
ws  = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('DB')

for row in DATA_FROM_DATABASE:
  obj = [row.year, row.date, row.product, row.amount]

  for j in range(len(obj)):
    ws.cell(column=j+1, row=i).value = obj[j]

workbook.save('out.xlsx')
```

On the file out.xlsx, the columns 1 from len(obj) from worksheet DB get set to hidden and the first column from the first worksheet. Is there a way to fix this or to set all the columns back to visible?

Comment: Well, the answer below is OK, but it doesn't address the problem (which I'm seeing as well). Really annoying behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide columns using the relevant ColumnDimension object:

```
col_d = ws.column_dimensions['A']
col_d.hidden = False
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while using openpyxl 2.2.6.

Columns are hidden for uncertain reason in new created files.

But problem solved when I upgrade openpyxl to 2.3.3.

So if you still have this issue, maybe try to upgrade the module to latest version.